# (Javascript) Take Three Integers From User to Display Sum, Average, Product, Smallest, and Largest Number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, dialog, average

The first issue that I'm having is with displaying the smallest and largest of the three numbers. Two separate alerts are appearing - the first alert says that the second-largest number is the largest (because it hasn't yet taken the third number into consideration), and the second alert correctly states that the largest number of the three is the largest. Not sure why this is happening - I just need one alert.

The second issue that I'm having is with displaying the sum, average, and product. When I try to run this code the page just goes blank - it doesn't work at all. Right now this portion of the code is commented out. Please help if you know what the problem is. I will need all of this information to display in the same alert. Thank you. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/xzsf8ca4/8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Fig. 6.14: welcome5.html -->
<!-- Using equality and relational operators. -->
<html>
   <head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Compare Numbers</title>
    <h1 style = "text-align:center">Compare the Integers!</h1>
    <script>

     var firstNumber; // first string entered by the user
     var secondNumber; // second string entered by the user
     var thirdNumber; // third string entered by the user
     var sum; // add the integers
     var average; // add the integers, divide by 3
     var product; // multiply the integers

     // enter first number from user as a string
     firstNumber = window.prompt("Enter first integer");

     // enter second number from user as a string
     secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

     // enter third number from user as a string
     thirdNumber = window.prompt("Enter third integer");

     // convert numbers from strings to integers
     firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
     secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);
     thirdNumber = parseInt(thirdNumber);

     //determine result
     if (firstNumber > secondNumber && thirdNumber)
        window.alert(firstNumber + " is largest");

     if (secondNumber > firstNumber && thirdNumber)
        window.alert(secondNumber + " is largest"); 

     if (thirdNumber > firstNumber && secondNumber)
        window.alert(thirdNumber + " is largest");
    //determine sum, average, and product
    /*
     sum (firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber)
        window.alert("the sum is "); 
     average ((firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber) / 3))
        window.alert("the average is ");
     product (firstNumber * secondNumber * thirdNumber)
        window.alert("the product is");
    */ 


// end if
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please throughout this answer. I embed logic to a function and call once all 3 numbers found and logic also change

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Fig. 6.14: welcome5.html -->
<!-- Using equality and relational operators. -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Compare Numbers</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var firstNumber, // first string entered by the user
                secondNumber, // second string entered by the user
                thirdNumber, // third string entered by the user
                sum, // add the integers
                average, // add the integers, divide by 3
                product; // multiply the integers

            // enter first number from user as a string
            firstNumber = window.prompt("Enter first integer");

            // enter second number from user as a string
            secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

            // enter third number from user as a string
            thirdNumber = window.prompt("Enter third integer");

            // convert numbers from strings to integers
            firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
            secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);
            thirdNumber = parseInt(thirdNumber);
            findLargNum(firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber);

            function findLargNum(firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber){
                //determine result
                if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
                    if(firstNumber > thirdNumber) window.alert(firstNumber + " is largest");
                }
                else if(secondNumber > thirdNumber) window.alert(secondNumber + " is largest");
                else window.alert(thirdNumber + " is largest");

                var sum =  firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;
                window.alert("the sum is " + sum); 
                var average = (firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber) / 3;
                window.alert("the average is " + average);var product = firstNumber * secondNumber * thirdNumber;window.alert("the product is" + product);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style = "text-align:center">Compare the Integers!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var firstNumber, // first string entered by the user
 secondNumber, // second string entered by the user
 thirdNumber, // third string entered by the user
 sum, // add the integers
 average, // add the integers, divide by 3
 product; // multiply the integers

// enter first number from user as a string
firstNumber = window.prompt("Enter first integer");

// enter second number from user as a string
secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

// enter third number from user as a string
thirdNumber = window.prompt("Enter third integer");

// convert numbers from strings to integers
firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);
thirdNumber = parseInt(thirdNumber);
findLargNum(firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber);

function findLargNum(firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber){
 //determine result
 if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
  if(firstNumber > thirdNumber) window.alert(firstNumber + " is largest");
 }
 else if(secondNumber > thirdNumber) window.alert(secondNumber + " is largest");
 else window.alert(thirdNumber + " is largest");
 
 var sum =  firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;
 window.alert("the sum is " + sum); 
 var average = (firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber) / 3;
 window.alert("the average is " + average);var product = firstNumber * secondNumber * thirdNumber;window.alert("the product is" + product);
}
```

```html
<h1 style = "text-align:center">Compare the Integers!</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know we needed else and else if. Now I need to display the sum, average, and product (the portion of code that is commented out).

Comment: please check the answer I added the full working code

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the problem of the dialog boxes not showing up still exists: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/frpks9sd/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenti/hkeddorh/
Please check jsfiddle its work fine for me

Comment: I must have missed a small detail somewhere. Working perfectly now. Thank you kind sir / ma'am.

Answer (score 1):

```
//  Initialising variables
var number1, number2, number3, sum, average, product, largest, smallest;

//Inpuing the Numbers 
// parseInt is used to covert the var to integer value or else the result will be concatenation of all the values
number1 = parseInt(window.prompt('Enter Number 1 :'));
number2 = parseInt(window.prompt('Enter Number 2 :'));
number3 = parseInt(window.prompt('Enter Number 3 :'));

// Adding the Numbers
sum = number1 + number2 + number3;

// Finding the average
average = parseInt(sum) / 3;

// Finding Product 
product = number1 * number2 * number3;

// Checking the Largest value
if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3) {
    largest = number1;
} else if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3) {
    largest = number2;
} else {
    largest = number3;
}

//Checking the smallest value

if (number1 < number2 && number1 < number3) {
    smallest = number1;
} else if (number2 < number1 && number2 < number3) {
    smallest = number2;
} else {
    smallest = number3;
}

//Returning or Printing Result in Alert box
window.alert('Sum : ' + sum + '\nAverage : ' + average.toFixed(2) + '\nProduct : ' + product + '\nLargest : ' + largest + '\nSmallest : ' + smallest);
```

Comment: please write a little description about what you did

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>

     var firstNumber; 
     var secondNumber;
     var thirdNumber;

     firstNumber = window.prompt("Enter number");

     secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter another number");

     thirdNumber = window.prompt("Enter third number");



     if (firstNumber > secondNumber && firstNumber > thirdNumber)
        window.alert(firstNumber + " is largest");

     else if (secondNumber > firstNumber && secondNumber > thirdNumber)
        window.alert(secondNumber + " is largest"); 

     else if (thirdNumber > firstNumber && thirdNumber > secondNumber)
        window.alert(thirdNumber + " is largest");

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your attempt to help. Your answer could however benefit from some explanations in prose and from being formatted for better readability. Please take the [tour] to get many useful hints.